# Why am I getting an Error 'Invalid object name #temp3'

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have 3 tables (tb_cdcp_ATQchild, tb_cdcp_ATQInfant, tb_cdcp_ATQPreschool) that look similar to the first table below. Based on the IndividualID and the createdate, I need to count all IndividualIDs where the second number is lower than the first number. For example, for IndividualID = 7029AF536A9EB4B1697D, 1/18/19 has a total of 9 if you count C_Q1 through C_Q5, 1/19/19 has a total of 5 if you count C_Q1 through C_Q5, so that IndividualID would get a count of 1 since the 2nd number is lower than the first number. I have 3 tables that look just like with same logic. The 4th table- tb_cdcp_ANSchecklist - second table below - has True and False and needs to be included with the other 3 tables with the logic being a little different. So for 7029AF536A9EB4B1697D in the tb_cdcp_ANSchecklist table, 11/22/19 has a count of 6 trues and 12/3/19 has 6 falses - If there are more falses in the second entry then the first entry then that IndividualID gets counted as 1, but even if the individualid has more than one table where the second number is lower than the first number, the IndividualID only gets a count of 1. It's very confusing what I need to do, so hopefully it makes sense.

[image: tb_cdcp_ATQchild]

[image: tb_cdcp_ANSChecklist]

Comment: Impossible to know without replicating it, but the SQL above doesn't look right anyway. What are you *actually* trying to achieve here?

Comment: I need to compare the data. I have other queries that do the same thing but from different views and insert into different temp tables. Then I need to compare the data from the different temp tables to get a total row count. This is the only way I can think how to do it.

Comment: You just want a row count from each table?

Comment: Yes, from each of the temp tables that have the final data. I have 4 temp tables I will need to query from - #temp3, #temp6, #temp9, and #temp12. I will need to get the final count from the rownum column of all 4 tables. I will then need to have it run with SSRS with converting the queries to stored procedure(s) possibly. Not sure if that's possible

Comment: But the data from those tables is coming from elsewhere. YOu should really be showing us what your data looks like before you mess with it, and the results you are after. It looks like you're hugely over complicating the issue.

Comment: I edited my post to show you the original tables where the data is coming from and how I need to calculate the data between all of the tables.

Answer (score 0):

> Temp tables exist only for the current session.

So, if you are running `Select * from #temp3` in a separate query window then this error will occur.  Temp tables exist only for the current session

Comment: Okay. It works in the same query window as when I run the insert query. Can you tell me if I would be able to use Insert/Update temp table queries as a stored procedure so that it can be used in SSRS?